# Firebase Storage - Wait till all upload tasks are completed before executing function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using the following code to upload one or multiple files to Firebase Storage. When the upload is completed the downloadURL is logged in the console.

I would like to execute another function when all the files are uploaded, outside the forEach function. How can I print the console log when all the uploads tasks are completed?

```
onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { files } = this.state;

    files.forEach(file => {
        const uploadTask = Storage.ref(`files/${file.name}`).put(file);

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            console.log(progress);
        }, error => { console.log(error) }, () => {
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                console.log(downloadURL);
            });
        });
    });

    //Wait till all uploads are completed
    console.log('all uploads complete');
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask) objects behave just like promises, as they have [then()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) and catch() methods.  So, you can collect them all into an array and use `Promise.all()` to generate a another promise that resolves when all the uploads are complete.

```
const promises = [];
files.forEach(file => {
    const uploadTask = Storage.ref(`files/${file.name}`).put(file);
    promises.push(uploadTask);

    uploadTask.on('state_changed', snapshot => {
        const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        console.log(progress);
    }, error => { console.log(error) }, () => {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
            console.log(downloadURL);
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(promises).then(tasks => {
    console.log('all uploads complete');
});
```

Comment: Is there also a way to execute the console.log(downloadURL) before the console.log inside the Promise.all callback?

Comment: This sounds like a different question you might want to ask here on SO.