# How to execute a function after uploading files to Firebase Storage (Web)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

I want to execute some code after the uploading of files has completed. The problem I'm running into is that the promise from my `Promise.all()` method I'm using to upload files is returning asynchronously. I've tried running some code after getting the `downloadURL` information of the last file in my `files` array, but the timing of execution is inconsistent.

Here's what I'm trying:

```js
   let lastFileName = files[files.length - 1].name;
      Promise.all(
        files.map(item => {
          const storageRef = firebase
            .storage()
            .ref()
            .child(`test/${item.name}`)
            .put(item);

          return storageRef.on(
            firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
            snapshot => {...},
            error => {...},
            () => {
              storageRef.snapshot.ref
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then(downloadURL => {
                 if (lastFileName === item.name) {
                    someFunc();
                    }
                });
            }
          );
        })
      ).then(() => alert("firing asynchronously"));
```

the `.then(() => alert("firing asynchronously"));` code is firing immediately upon file submission

Answer (score 0):

What you call `storageRef` is actually a [`UploadTask` instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask.html). And [`UploadTask.on(`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask.html#on) does not return a promise, so your `return storageRef.on(` returns something different then you expect. It returns a custom function that can be used to remove the listener, which immediately satisfies the `Promise` contract.

I think what you're looking to do is return a promise that resolves to the download URL, which you can do with something like:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  storageRef.on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    snapshot => {...},
    error => { reject(error); },
    () => {
      storageRef.snapshot.ref
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(downloadURL => {
          if (lastFileName === item.name) {
            resolve(downloadURL);
          }
        }).catch(error) { reject(error); }
    }
```

Comment: I just found Doug's answer here that works pretty well => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372789/firebase-storage-wait-till-all-upload-tasks-are-completed-before-executing-fun?rq=1

Comment: That just logs the download URL, which means you can't yet use it in  your `).then(() => alert("firing asynchronously"));` But if that is all you need, go for it!

Comment: Originally all I was looking to do was fire some function after all files had been uploaded, but I'll keep your solution in mind as well.